# Passing a value from a custom controller to a specific template

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to update the user profile template with information from a custom module.

For example, in the controller, I am using the following code.

```
$build ['send_data'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'my_custom_template',
  '#content' => $result,           
);
```

I also implemented `hook_theme()` using the following code.

```
function my_custom_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'my_custom_template' => [
      'variables' => ['content' => NULL,]
    ],
  ];
}
```

It works perfectly in the custom template when I use `{{ content }}`

But now, when i try to send value to 'user template' 
i got no result on my page

i am using the following code

.controller (current module) :

```
$build ['user'] = array(
        '#theme' => 'user',
        '#campagne' => $result,
    );
return $build
```

.module (current module) :

```
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'user' => array(
      'template' => 'user',
      // This array contains the default values.
      // You should not use a PHP variable.
      'variables' => array('campagne' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}    

function hook_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
   $variables['campagne'] = $result;
}
```

user.html.twig (external module template)

```
{{ campagne }}
```

Comment: I can't see anything obvious. Have you flushed the cache? Also typically theme definitions are prefixed with there module name so there are no name collisions.

Comment: My template user is a default template and have a preprocess function so the name 'user' already exist

Comment: Your `$content` variable is NULL by default. If it's going to get passed to Element::children() without checking if it's set, then you should set it be an empty array instead of NULL perhaps. Declare it as `'content' => []`  instead of `'content' => NULL` in your hook_theme.

Comment: To pass the variable to the user template, you need to preprocess the user theme. Use `hook_preprocess_user` and set your `$variables['content'] = $result` BUT you should probably choose a better name than `content` as you may overwrite what's already there. Generate it like you do in your view builder controller.

Comment: `hook_preprocess_user` function's `hook` needs to be replaced by your module's name. `hook` is basically `my_module` going by your examples.